# Zend Framework 'AjaxContent' & ResponseSegmentation problem

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I'm using jquery in Zend Framework, it's my first trial.
I've already found out through [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565235/jquery-and-zend-framework-problem), that I can change the response by changing the context like so:

```
$ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
$ajaxContext->addActionContext('myaction', 'html');
$ajaxContext->initContext();
```

Now this has helped a lot but a new problem has shown:

My page consists of different responseSegments and when I responde to an Ajax request by changing the Context, my other ResponseSegments also 'think' they are sending Ajax but they're not. The front controller asks for a viewscript.ajax.phtml... which is wrong, it should be viewscript.phtml (exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I figured out how to solve this and because I think others will encounter the same problem in the future, I will answer my own question here:

In my ActionSetup.php (or bootstrap.php if the action setup is not separated) I needed to make sure that actions are only pushed to the action stack, if the request was no XmlHttpRequest.

The only thing that was missing was an if statement:

```
if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest())
```

The whole thing looks like that:

```
/**
 * Front Controller plugin to set up the action stack.
 *
 */
class Project_Controller_Plugin_ActionSetup extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
            if (!$front->hasPlugin('Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack'))
            {
                $actionStack = new Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack();
                $front->registerPlugin($actionStack, 97);
            } else
            {
                $actionStack = $front->getPlugin('Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack');
            }

            $menuAction = clone ($request);
            $menuAction->setActionName('menu')
            ->setControllerName('index');
            $actionStack->pushStack($menuAction);

            $userlogAction = clone ($request);
            $userlogAction->setActionName('userlog')
            ->setControllerName('index');
            $actionStack->pushStack($userlogAction);

           //etc.
        }
    }
}
```